# Adding a developer to an Apple Developer account

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I have an Apple Developer iOS Membership. I have hired a developer to write an iOS app for me. They said they don't have their own account so in order for us to test the app using `ad-hoc provisioning` we'll need to use my account.  When I go to invite users into my account from the Member Center I am given 2 options to add this user as, 1) `Admin`, 2) `Member`.  Is the correct way to give a developer access and which option should I give them?  I want to give the least amount of privileges as possible.  I don't want them to access any sensitive account information, just allow them to develop the app and allow for testing.

This is the overview of the roles but I am still not sure which is correct
https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what level of involvement you want to have with the project.  In order to manage the full development life-cycle for an app you need to create provisioning files, generate certificates for distribution, generate App IDs ect.  You can add you developer as a member but in that case many of these functions will have to be done by you as the admin.  In the case of certificates (for distribution, push notifications etc) the 'member' can request them but they still need to be approved by an 'admin'.

So, if you want to give the least amount of privileges stick with the 'member option with the understanding that you will need to be involved periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Member` is what you should go for.